# What is the best way to SELECT data when there are two possible tables holding the detail information?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that holds product information, specifically the packaging weights of products by material.  Not every product has actual packaging weights so there is a system to determine mean weights for these products by grouping them together.

For example, if there is a new product "Can of beans" then this might be put into a group called "Cans".  Other products in the "Cans" group will have packaging weights so there is a calculation to determine the mean weights for the group (by material).

When presenting the weights data I want to use actual weights if they are available and fallback onto using group weights if they aren't.  The problem is that the relationship between products and actual weights/ group weights is one to many, so there is the potential to return multiple rows of duplicate data if a product has both actual and group weights.

In the live system there are around 10 million products and over 3 million weights so I need a solution that performs well.

My current method is to just select all the rows and then take the AVG of the weight but this seems like a rather "clunky" solution.  Is there a better way to do this?

I have a (rather long) example using made up data:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (
    ProductId INT,
    GroupId INT,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductId));
DECLARE @Group TABLE (
    GroupId INT,
    GroupName VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupId));
DECLARE @Material TABLE (
    MaterialId INT,
    MaterialName VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (MaterialId));
DECLARE @ProductWeight TABLE (
    ProductId INT,
    MaterialId INT,
    [Weight] NUMERIC(19,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductId, MaterialId));
DECLARE @GroupWeight TABLE (
    GroupId INT,
    MaterialId INT,
    [Weight] NUMERIC(19,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupId, MaterialId));

--Materials, only three for this example
INSERT INTO @Material VALUES (1, 'Paper');
INSERT INTO @Material VALUES (2, 'Steel');
INSERT INTO @Material VALUES (3, 'Glass');

--Two groups, one for cans and one for bottles
INSERT INTO @Group VALUES (1, 'Cans');
INSERT INTO @Group VALUES (2, 'Bottles');

--Five products, two "cans" and three "bottles"
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (1, 1, 'Can of soup');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (2, 1, 'Can of beans');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (3, 2, 'Bottle of beer');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (4, 2, 'Bottle of wine');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (5, 2, 'Bottle of sauce');

--Three products have actual weights
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (1, 1, 5.2);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (1, 2, 23.1);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (3, 1, 4.6);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (3, 2, 2.4);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (3, 3, 185.9);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (4, 1, 5.1);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (4, 2, 2.6);
INSERT INTO @ProductWeight VALUES (4, 3, 650.4);

--Calculate the group weights
INSERT INTO @GroupWeight 
SELECT p.GroupId, pw.MaterialId, AVG(pw.[Weight]) 
FROM @ProductWeight pw INNER JOIN @Product p ON p.ProductId = pw.ProductId
GROUP BY p.GroupId, pw.MaterialId;

--Now display the product information, use the actual weights where available and the group weights otherwise
SELECT
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialName,
    CASE WHEN pw.[Weight] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Product' ELSE 'Group' END AS WeightSource,
    AVG(COALESCE(pw.[Weight], gw.[Weight])) AS [Weight]
FROM
    @Product p
    LEFT JOIN @ProductWeight pw ON pw.ProductId = p.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN @GroupWeight gw ON gw.GroupId = p.GroupId
    LEFT JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = COALESCE(pw.MaterialId, gw.MaterialId)
GROUP BY
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialName,
    CASE WHEN pw.[Weight] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Product' ELSE 'Group' END;
```

When this runs it returns the data in exactly the format I want, including the weight source, i.e. if it is an actual weight or a group weight:

```
ProductName     MaterialName    WeightSource    Weight
Bottle of beer  Glass           Product         185.900000
Bottle of beer  Paper           Product         4.600000
Bottle of beer  Steel           Product         2.400000
Bottle of sauce Glass           Group           418.150000
Bottle of sauce Paper           Group           4.850000
Bottle of sauce Steel           Group           2.500000
Bottle of wine  Glass           Product         650.400000
Bottle of wine  Paper           Product         5.100000
Bottle of wine  Steel           Product         2.600000
Can of beans    Paper           Group           5.200000
Can of beans    Steel           Group           23.100000
Can of soup     Paper           Product         5.200000
Can of soup     Steel           Product         23.100000
```

But I can't help feeling there must be a more efficient way to do this?

Edit - I had a go at using UNION ALL, maybe I am missing something as this is the best I could come up with?

```
WITH RawData AS (
SELECT
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialName,
    'Product' AS WeightSource,
    pw.[Weight]
FROM
    @Product p
    INNER JOIN @ProductWeight pw ON pw.ProductId = p.ProductId
    INNER JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = pw.MaterialId
UNION ALL
SELECT
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialName,
    'Group' AS WeightSource,
    gw.[Weight]
FROM
    @Product p
    INNER JOIN @GroupWeight gw ON gw.GroupId = p.GroupId
    INNER JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = gw.MaterialId),
RankedWeightSource AS (
SELECT
    ProductName,
    WeightSource,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName ORDER BY WeightSource DESC) AS RowRank
FROM
    RawData
GROUP BY 
    ProductName,
    WeightSource),
BestWeightSource AS (
SELECT
    ProductName,
    WeightSource
FROM
    RankedWeightSource
WHERE
    RowRank = 1)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    RawData rd
    INNER JOIN BestWeightSource bws ON bws.ProductName = rd.ProductName AND bws.WeightSource = rd.WeightSource;
```

Comment: You could probably `CROSS APPLY` something involving a `UNION ALL` statement.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Shouldn't a `UNION ALL` be enough?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Sure. You could stick it in a subquery or CTE but I personally feel `CROSS APPLY` would be the most concise in this scenario. I use `CROSS APPLY` when it's going to be something like "and now non-trivially calculate this value" the same way a user defined table function might be used.

Comment: @ta.speot.is That's what I was thinking of. Never thought of CROSS APPLY though, I'll have to review it and see what's possible.

Comment: Or if you don't mind maintaining more than one object, stick the `UNION ALL` in `vwProductAndWeights`

Comment: Yes, I didn't consider UNION ALL and I suppose this would work.  But isn't this going to essentially be doing the same work, i.e. select all the rows and then ditch the ones that aren't actually required.

Comment: @RichardHansell Look at the execution plans. If you have sensible indexes SQL Server will be seeking (to the rows in question) instead of scanning (potentially reading over rows that aren't required).

Comment: Okay, I had a go at this and I don't think UNION ALL helps at all.  Can you give an example of how you would use either UNION ALL or APPLY to get the data out?

Comment: I posted my answer while you were editing to add your ranking version, which is why mine looks a lot like yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done before in a similar situation is introduce a raw query with all possible values, along with the **precedence** of the value; then use a `ROW_NUMBER` outer query to get just the value with the highest precedence.

I'm going to use your (excellent) sample data, and everything goes after the insert into `@GroupWeight`.

This is our raw data:

```
-- the product weights (use INNER JOIN to only find 
--   the products with their own weights)
SELECT
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialId,
    m.MaterialName,
    pw.Weight,
    'Product' WeightSource,
    20 Precedence
FROM
    @Product p
    INNER JOIN @ProductWeight pw ON pw.ProductId = p.ProductId
    INNER JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = pw.MaterialId
UNION ALL
-- the group weight
SELECT
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialId,
    m.MaterialName,
    gw.Weight,
    'Group' WeightSource,
    10 Precedence
FROM
    @Product p
    INNER JOIN @GroupWeight gw on gw.GroupId = p.GroupId
    INNER JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = gw.MaterialId
```

This will return one row for each product-material with a specific weight, plus one row for each product-material. Each row indicates whether it is a product weight or a group weight.

We can then number the rows, ordering by precedence:

```
-- assume the above is in a CTE named AllWeights
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, MaterialId 
                       ORDER BY Precedence DESC) rn
FROM 
    AllWeights
```

Which gives us the same data with an additional indication of which row for a given product-material is the relevant one, so finally we can get just that:

```
-- assume the above is in a CTE named RowNumbered
SELECT
    ProductName,
    MaterialName,
    WeightSource,
    Weight
FROM
    RowNumbered
WHERE
    rn = 1
;
```

And we're done.

---

Putting it all together:

```
;WITH AllWeights AS (
-- the product weights (use INNER JOIN to only find 
--   the products with their own weights)
SELECT
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialId,
    m.MaterialName,
    pw.Weight,
    'Product' WeightSource,
    20 Precedence
FROM
    @Product p
    INNER JOIN @ProductWeight pw ON pw.ProductId = p.ProductId
    INNER JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = pw.MaterialId
UNION ALL
-- the group weight
SELECT
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    m.MaterialId,
    m.MaterialName,
    gw.Weight,
    'Group' WeightSource,
    10 Precedence
FROM
    @Product p
    INNER JOIN @GroupWeight gw on gw.GroupId = p.GroupId
    INNER JOIN @Material m ON m.MaterialId = gw.MaterialId
),
RowNumbered AS (
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, MaterialId 
                       ORDER BY Precedence DESC) rn
FROM 
    AllWeights
)
SELECT
    ProductName,
    MaterialName,
    WeightSource,
    Weight
FROM
    RowNumbered
WHERE
    rn = 1
;
```

Output:

```
ProductName          MaterialName WeightSource Weight
-------------------- ------------ ------------ ------------
Can of soup          Paper        Product      5.20
Can of soup          Steel        Product      23.10
Can of beans         Paper        Group        5.20
Can of beans         Steel        Group        23.10
Bottle of beer       Paper        Product      4.60
Bottle of beer       Steel        Product      2.40
Bottle of beer       Glass        Product      185.90
Bottle of wine       Paper        Product      5.10
Bottle of wine       Steel        Product      2.60
Bottle of wine       Glass        Product      650.40
Bottle of sauce      Paper        Group        4.85
Bottle of sauce      Steel        Group        2.50
Bottle of sauce      Glass        Group        418.15
```

which except for order is the same as yours, I think.

You'll have to check performance yourself, of course.

Comment: Cool, this works nicely and is better than the UNION ALL solution I came up with.  I particularly like the introduction of the precedence so that you can use this in your ROW_NUMBER().  However, I tested this against my original solution and it is actually slightly slower, I get roughly 43% for my first query and 57% for yours when executed back-to-back.  I am going to try this on the real dataset and see if this perfomance scales the same way.

Comment: Well the good news is that when I put this logic into the production version and ran it for half a million products there was a clear IMPROVEMENT in performance.  This time my original method was 59% and your method was 41%, so that's quite a decent improvement AND the script is more readable now.  In my production environment things are a lot more complex than the simplified example I gave.  For example, there are five potential weight sources and there are also levels of packaging, packaging types, packaging units, etc. to worry about.

Comment: @RichardHansell I don't know if you already know this, but if you don't, and for anyone else watching: [even when SSMS is told to Include Actual Execution Plan, the "Query cost (relative to the batch)" figures is still based on cost **estimates**, which can be far off actuals](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24617)

Comment: @AkashM - no I wasn't aware of that, but I am now so thanks again.  In the end I did a simple (not the most accurate, but near enough for my purposes) test by creating two views, one works the original way and the other works the new "improved" way.  Both views returned 55,281,074 rows when run across the entire database with nothing else executing.  The original method took 03:32 and the new method took 02:55 so that is a clear improvement of the order I was expecting?